# Browser Automations ( using Webdriver ) when running from Jenkins  are running as Process but not visibl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Details :
- Developed a test automation framework using Webdriver and TestNG
- Using ANT as triggering tool to drive browser automations. This is working fine, I could see Browser getting opened and see all the navigations
- Setup Jenkins on my local & configured to invoke ANT
- Clicked on Build Now link in the Job
- Browser is not visible, instead running as a process...could see it in Windows Task Manager

Any help / Inputs / Pointers is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running Jenkins in the background using the executable provided with it, you need to run it in the foreground: `java -jar jenkins.war [other options]`. Also, make sure you are looking at the machine where Jenkins is actually run. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620206/1178189).

Comment: Hi, this is working fine but when i am trying to access my local jenkins from other machine using http://<my_machine>:8080/, it is not able to connect to my local jenkins. Instead if jenkins is started as windows as service , i could access it from other machines also. Any suggestions how this can be achieved ?

Comment: when i access it from my machine its working fine. But when i do it from other machine (http://<my_machine>:8080/) it could not connect to jenkins!!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you dump your environment (`http://localhost:8080/systemInfo` -> Save As -> text only) for both cases and post to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?