# Selenium tests fail when run by Jenkins, but succeed when run by command line

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I have two virtual machines running Windows Server 2012. One is running Jenkins, and another that is running one of Jenkins' build jobs.  The job checks out test code from subversion and then runs `mvn test -Dtest=com.package.name.TestName` in a windows batch script.  The test compiles and runs, but fails with an `ElementNotVisibleException`.  These are TestNG tests with Selenium and a Firefox driver.

If I take the exact same command and run it from the Windows command line, the test succeeds.  Another thing I notice is that when run from the command line, the browser window appears and I can watch it run through the test, but when run by Jenkins no window appears.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935897/jenkins-running-selenium-tests-without-opening-browser) that suggests this is because our Jenkins is running as a service, and the tests are written to require a browser window in the foreground.  Altering the tests to use a headless driver isn't an option for us, as that will result in inaccurate test results.  Is there a way to get these tests working with Jenkins?

Comment: why not just use a grid?  fire up a grid with at least 1 node then you'll be golden

Comment: Looking into Selenium Grid now.

Comment: @sircapsalot: Selenium Grid did the job.  Thanks.  If you want to put your suggestion in an answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using the Selenium Grid. Its explicit function is to serve several different tests at the same time.

Your jenkins would fire off tests against the grid which would point all the tests towards your nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The best option will be to stop running Jenkins as a windows service. Open a command window and start Jenkins manually. In my case it worked.

Comment: This is what even I have tried and works like a charm. Download jenkins and start is as a service using java -jar jenkins.war This will solve the headless problem and might also solve element not found.

Comment: That was my first thought, but a senior build engineer here said that Jenkins needs to run as a service, otherwise failed tests could cause problems with the Jenkins instance.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar type of problem while running our selenium test using jenkins on firefox. Jenkins slave was installed as service and firefox was giving troubles. Our solution was to use service by machine administrator creadentials. You can do it by opening services.msc and right click on jenkins service -> properties -> log on. select this account and set administrator credentials. Restart the service and you are good to go.

Comment: Jenkins is already using our administrator account.  Thanks anyway.