# Selenium GUI tests keep failing when run from Jenkins (no such element)

Tags: maven, testing, selenium, jenkins

Selenium GUI tests are not getting executed after the build. Everything is getting done in Jenkins using Maven.

### T E S T S

Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/dashboard/workspace/modules/ui/DashboardDemo/DashboardDemo_home && /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/dashboard/workspace/modules/ui/DashboardDemo/DashboardDemo_home/target/surefire/surefirebooter4371762794186855568.jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/dashboard/workspace/modules/ui/DashboardDemo/DashboardDemo_home/target/surefire/surefire1890218106407957925tmp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/dashboard/workspace/modules/ui/DashboardDemo/DashboardDemo_home/target/surefire/surefire_02979456989362369392tmp
Running com.behavox.ui.demo.BudToneBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI
/home/invictuslabs/Downloads/chromedriver
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.0/logback-classic-1.0.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.6.4/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298611 (d1120fdf51badec2f7b63a96e19a58d4783de84d)) on port 26330
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.111][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
/home/invictuslabs/Downloads/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298611 (d1120fdf51badec2f7b63a96e19a58d4783de84d)) on port 22282
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.501][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 32.198 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.behavox.ui.demo.BudToneTradingPageTestUI
/home/invictuslabs/Downloads/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298611 (d1120fdf51badec2f7b63a96e19a58d4783de84d)) on port 17133
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.502][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
/home/invictuslabs/Downloads/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298611 (d1120fdf51badec2f7b63a96e19a58d4783de84d)) on port 28025
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.498][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 28.072 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.behavox.ui.demo.FredricHooverBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI
/home/invictuslabs/Downloads/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298611 (d1120fdf51badec2f7b63a96e19a58d4783de84d)) on port 15817
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.502][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
/home/invictuslabs/Downloads/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.11.298611 (d1120fdf51badec2f7b63a96e19a58d4783de84d)) on port 31752
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.502][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 28.211 sec <<< FAILURE!

And so on (there are quite a lot of tests). Then:

Results :

Tests in error: 
  navigationTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.BudToneBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  generalTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.BudToneBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  navigationTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.BudToneTradingPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  generalTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.BudToneTradingPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  navigationTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.FredricHooverBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  generalTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.FredricHooverBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  navigationTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.JohnSmithTradingPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  generalTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.JohnSmithTradingPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  navigationTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.JohnSmithBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI): no such element(..)
  generalTest(com.behavox.ui.demo.JohnSmithBehaviouralPatternPageTestUI): no such element(..)

And so on. At the very end of the log it gives me:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test (ui-test) on project DashboardDemo_home: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/dashboard/workspace/modules/ui/DashboardDemo/DashboardDemo_home/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.2:test (ui-test) on project DashboardDemo_home: There are test failures.

Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/dashboard/workspace/modules/ui/DashboardDemo/DashboardDemo_home/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

I run the same tests on the local machine from IDEA and it works perfectly well.

Another thing is that (I am not sure whether it is supposed to be like this) when I run my tests from Jenkins, Chrome is not getting opened for some reason. However, I cannot see the reason why and errors do not seem very informative to me. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I would double check all paths, permissions, updates and settings.  If the tests run locally it should at least build remotely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium tests fail when run by Jenkins, but succeed when run by command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101711/selenium-tests-fail-when-run-by-jenkins-but-succeed-when-run-by-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute GUI tests via Jenkins in headless mode.
Setup in Linux below:
http://scraping.pro/use-headless-firefox-scraping-linux/

OR 
you may have to use a head less browsers