# Webdriver-Jenkins, browser remains in background

Tags: browser, ant, jenkins, webdriver

I have a project where I am trying to execute webdriver testcases (keyword driven) from jenkins.
I am using Ant to build and execute the project. My code works fine from eclipse and command-line.

I am trying to use jenkins to run automation test eveynight. ( I have to use jenkins, can not use windows scheduler due to some dependencies.)

I can check out my code from SVN, compile it using ant and run it. But, while running, jenkins opens firefox and keeps it in background. It appears that tests are executing fine (in backgournd) but can not see firefox UI in foreground.

Any one had this problem before? or any solutions ?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I certainly don't understand your problem, I would prefer FF to run in the background on my machine, and I can't get it to go the background automatically, but the code works either way.  Regardless, have you tried `driver.manage().window().maximize()`?

Comment: It is a Jenkins issue. Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows

Comment: I'd consider that a feature!

Answer (score 1):

that a feature of jenkins called as the Execution of test cases in Headless browser mode