# Running Selenium test do not work on Jenkins

Tags: java, windows, selenium, jenkins

When I run my test on local machine all works fine. But when I move to Jenkins I get error `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session`
I do not get what can be wrong? I tested before simple test without Selenium and it works fine. In Jenkins I have linked my repo and run my test with gradle test.

Comment: Does your jenkins server have a browser on it? For the selenium tests to run, they will need some sort of browser - headless or real.

Comment: I have in my resources chromedriver.exe

Comment: And Jenkins is running on a Windows box with Chrome installed?

Comment: Which browser are you using to start your tests? Firefox has changed and need `geckodriver` for latest versions, what may lead for this kind of problem when running remotely. An option is also to set a docker image for Selenium Grid and Selenium Nodes to be used in a CI server. If you want to see, check their [Github Page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium).

Comment: @AshleyFrieze You where right I just need to install Chrome and now it works. But I have one more question. Is there a way to see those test running? Physically?

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

First answer is given by @ashley-frieze: You need to have Chrome Browser installed to to run test against it.

Second issue: To see the browser running, maybe take a look  at [Jenkins : Selenium GUI tests are not visible on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21878521/2354488) , where it is suggested to allow the service to "interact with desktop". Maybe that helps.