# Configure Jenkins to use Chrome - Selenium 3.0.1 Maven TestNG

Tags: java, maven, google-chrome, selenium, jenkins

I've been trying to get Jenkins to use Chrome for my automated tests. When I run the tests locally I am able to get it to use Chrome by -Dbrowser=chrome in JDK VM options for TestNG.

[image]

For some reason it seems to be stuck on using Firefox no matter what I try.

Here is my before method

```
@BeforeMethod(
    alwaysRun = true
)
public static void configureBrowserBeforeTest(Method testMethod) {
    try {
        ((Driver)driver.get()).resetBrowser();
        wait.set(newDefaultWait());
        userAgent = determineUserAgent();
        initialiseNewScreenshotCapture(testMethod);
    } catch (Exception var2) {
        logger.error("Failed to configure browser.", var2);
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to configure browser.", var2);
    }
}
```

And POM File

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.frameworkium</groupId>
    <artifactId>Frameworkium</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>2.0.5</version>

    <name>Frameworkium</name>
    <description>
        A template designed to get up and running quickly with Selenium and Appium.
    </description>
    <url/>
    <inceptionYear/>
    <organization/>
    <licenses/>

    <developers/>
    <contributors/>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <modules/>

    <scm/>
    <issueManagement/>
    <ciManagement/>
    <distributionManagement/>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <env.config>local</env.config>
        <threads>1</threads>
        <groups/>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.Frameworkium</groupId>
            <artifactId>frameworkium-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>
                    src/main/resources
                </directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tests</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <screenshotDirectory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/screenshots
                                </screenshotDirectory>
                                <allure.issues.tracker.pattern>
                                    /browse/%s
                                </allure.issues.tracker.pattern>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests*.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                                <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <groups>${groups}</groups>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                            </argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

[image]

I'm sure the solution is something simple, I have Jenkins running as a service and using a local admin account. I have installed the chromedriver plugin for jenkins as well as the Selenium plugin. The tests are being found OK but they are using Firefox and FF version 50 doesnt seem to work with the gecko driver on Selenium 3.0.1,  so I would rather use Chrome which I know works just fine but for the life of me I cant figure out how to tell Jenkins to use Chrome instead of FF. Thanks in advance for your help! And apologies if I've missed anything out.

OS - Windows Server 2012
Maven
TestNG
Selenium 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the default browser defined to be used is firefox and your test code is not able to find the browser flavour to use (via command line (or) JVM args (or) via parameters) so its defaulting to what it knows of viz., `firefox`.

I noticed that in your IntelliJ run configurations screenshot, you have specified the browser flavour using the JVM argument `-Dbrowser=chrome` but for some reason I don't see the same in your Jenkins configuration page screenshot.

You seem to be having something like this `clean install package -DBrowserName="$BROWSERNAME" -e`

Can you please change it to `clean install package -Dbrowser=$BROWSERNAME -e` (I dont think you need to enclose `$BROWSERNAME` with quotes and am assuming that `BROWSERNAME` refers to a valid parameter in your Jenkins configuration page )

That should basically take care of your issue.

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue. Its running as a headless browser, how do I get it to launch the browser?

Comment: Please check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows