# Jenkins : Selenium GUI tests not visible in browser when I click build w/o using command prompt

Tags: windows, maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

I simply want to navigate to Jenkins, click build, and see the test execution in the browser. **I don't** want to use the command java -jar jenkins.war in the command prompt to get the browser to appear when I run my automated test. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

They have a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows)

**Solution 1:** Enable "Allow service to interact with Desktop"
Tried it, it didn't work on my machine running in Windows 10

**Solution 2:** Through CMD using jenkins.war