# Jenkins , Selenium tests are not visible on windows

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

When I run my selenium test (Maven tests) from Jenkins (windows 7) I see only the console output. 
I don't see the real browsers getting opened. 
How can I configure Jenkins so that I can see the browsers running the test?

Comment: Duplicate/copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins : Selenium GUI tests are not visible on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows)