# Cucumber Selenium webdriver tests not execute with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have try to execute the tests which are integrate with cucumber and selenium via jenkins. Console shows that build is successful but I cannot see execution of tests(opening the browser and continue the user actions).

This automation project use cucumber and selenium webdriver. When I execute feature files though Intellij IDEA, its successfully executes. But not working with jenkins.

I have set the relevant settings(pom file path, Maven path, jdk path, cucumber report plugin enabled).

Comment: If on windows this helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows check out Shessuky answer with max upvotes

Comment: My guess is that you are using Windows. Running a webdriver test on jenkins does not result in visible execution, but Jenkins does execute the test. Default Windows behavior for Jenkins.

Comment: I have check the Shessuky's answer and its not working for me. I have installed jenkins using the windows installer and in the above mentioned thread says that we need to do it through command prompt

Comment: Have you tried to execute your tests from IDE using Maven? Or directly through maven?

Comment: Please enable the "Interactive detection service" from services.msc and change the properties for jenkins service as mentioned by @Grasshopper , you should get a prompt with "view the message" where you can see the execution