# How to run a cucumber maven project from jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I am trying to run a cucumber maven project from jenkins The test is running 1 but the browser is not opening the error is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@43556938
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@53b32d7
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.52 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My pom file is :

```
  <build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
<configuration>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.12.2</version>
<configuration>
<configuration>
<includes>
<include>**/ReservationRunnerTest.java</include>
</includes>
</configuration>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Please help , I have all the dependencies and My runner file name is ReservationRunnerTest.java

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows

Comment: Did you manage to solver your problem ? Or can you put more about your project, code and everything ?