# How to create a chrome driver instance in Jenkins rather than running headless?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am new to Jenkins and I am facing an issue.

**When I build the job, chrome is running Headless only and I need actually to run chrome with UI.**

When I run the project via cmd or via eclipse, chrome is opening. 
I believe I used the standard setting of Jenkins and I am on Windows Platform, using Selenium and Java.
Is there any extra plugin I need to install or have I mistakenly installed any wrong one ?

Thank You guys in advance.

Comment: How are you starting Jenkins? (Service or command line?)

Comment: via service on localhost.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9668165/4121744) - you probably need to start Jenkins up manually from the command line instead of using the service.

Comment: thanks a lot, buddy, it actually worked.