# Jenkins does not open browser when running Selenium Python tests

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, pytest

I am running selenium python tests via jenkins. 
Here is the command

```
c:
cd C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProject\Selenium\
python loginTest.py
```

This test is for doing a login on web application. It runs fine from command line.
From jenkins it is successfull, but does not open the browser.

Here is the jenkins output

```
Running tests... 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 test_login_valid (__main__.LoginTests) ... OK (4.653058)s

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0:00:13

OK

Generating HTML reports... 

C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Selenium\POMDemo\Tests>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I am using Jenkins on the same system where I am able to run from commandline.

Here is the code of loginTest.py file

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import unittest
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))
from POMDemo.Pages.loginPage import LoginPage
from POMDemo.Pages.homePage import HomePage
import HtmlTestRunner

class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe")
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_login_valid(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")

        login = LoginPage(driver)
        login.enter_username("Admin")
        login.enter_password("admin123")
        login.click_login()

        homepage = HomePage(driver)
        homepage.click_welcome()
        homepage.click_logout()
        time.sleep(2)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()
        print("Test Completed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Selenium/reports'))
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.0

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows

Comment: @Chandila07 I have already seen this and I am already running jenkins from cmd (java -jar jenkins.war) but still its not showing browser