# When I run my test through jenkins chrome browser is not triggered and also showing testng.xml file is not matching

Tags: selenium, jenkins

[image]

Chrome browser is not launching when I click the build now link in jenkins, but showing build is success.

Solution provided in [Jenkins : Selenium GUI tests are not visible on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618774/jenkins-selenium-gui-tests-are-not-visible-on-windows) are not working for me. Someone please help me in this.

```
Started by user Karthick Ragu
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\killerFramework
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 51445
[karthick.framework] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java" -cp "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.13.jar;C:\Program Files\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven" "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.35.jar" "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar" "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar" 51445
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\LEARNING\sel\karthick.framework\pom.xml clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< web.automation.killer:karthick.framework >--------------
[INFO] Building karthick.framework 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ karthick.framework ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\LEARNING\sel\karthick.framework\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ karthick.framework ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ karthick.framework ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ karthick.framework ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ karthick.framework ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to D:\LEARNING\sel\karthick.framework\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) @ karthick.framework ---
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.339 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-06T23:35:41+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\LEARNING\sel\karthick.framework\pom.xml to web.automation.killer/karthick.framework/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/karthick.framework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: How you installed Jenkin in your machine? Are you starting/running Jenkins using apache tomcat server?

Comment: If you have installed Jenkins using exe file, the try running jenkins with Jenkins.WAR file deployment using apache tomcat local serversetup

Comment: Im running through jenkins.war from cmd only. also tried with jenkis exe but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The error is loud and clear

> Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern:
>   **/testng-results.xml Did not find any matching files.

That mean Jenkins not able to found xml file as per the path you have provided in jenkins.

Check if the path or filename is fine.
Put the full absolute path first to check and then try to create ** relative path

Comment: I have tried by giving the exact path eventhough chrome is not launching and showing the same message in console. ```TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: D:\LEARNING\sel\karthick.framework\test-output\testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: SUCCESS```

Comment: Test-output is testng report file folder name... testng.xml should be on root of your project

Comment: Yeah I kept my testng.xml file in root of the project.