# How can I run pywinauto testcases through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: user-interface, jenkins, testing, pywinauto

We need a mechanism for running GUI based testcases written using pywinauto ( on windows VM ) using Jenkins. Is it possible to have unattended execution ?

Comment: pywinauto will require active desktop window. By default Jenkins will not show UI to you. change some setting like in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21878521/5400362, then configure your testcases and run the Jenkins job.

Comment: Maybe this list of recipes will help: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html